# Xamarin.UITest REPL. How to get list of objects from ListView element?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nunit

How can i get Length of "grid_table" element?
I have the following REPL tree output:
[image: RELP tree outuup]

For now I can only get the "grid_table" element, but not its "container" elements or at least "grid_table" Length. Is it possible? Or I can only get elements by "container" Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To count all direct children for grid_table, use:

```
app.Query(q => q.Id("grid_table").Child()).Length
```

To count all elements with id 'container' that are descendants of "grid_table", you could use:

```
app.Query(q => q.Id("grid_table").Descendant().Id("container")).Length
```

Comment: Hi, @Ruud Kobes, I've already reached my goal with this line of code:
var lv = App.Query(q => q.Id("grid_table").Child("LinearLayout"));

But thanks :)