# How to query a child element, present inside a list item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, automation, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I want to automate the below scenario using Xamarin.UITest:

The List has several rows and each row has different elements inside it. 
I want to iterate through the list and find elements inside each row using Xamarin.

```cs
    IList CellList = app.Query(thisObject => thisObject.Id("MyList_ID"));

    foreach(var element in CellList)

    {

    //Here I want to go inside each row and find an element inside each row. So what needs to be changed in the below line of code? 

    bool isNTextPresent = (app.Query(thisObject => thisObject.Id("NText_ID")).Length) == 1 ? true : false;

    Assert.AreEqual(isNTextPresent , true);

    }
```

Comment: `Xamarin.UItest` provides the **Descendant** method which can help to get all the descendants of the element. If you want to get access to some element in the list, try to use the `Index` function. For example, `app.Query(q => q.Id("element_id").Descendant().Index(1)`. You could google with the keyword as **Finding and Using Different Types of Xamarin.UITest Locators** to check the related tutorial.

Comment: @y3z1 i am aware of this Descendant method. But the point is, the line of code you've mentioned in the comment, will just fetch that particular list item (in my case). I want to find an element inside my  " listitem " . How to do that ?

Comment: To get the element inside the item, try to add `.Child()` function. You could also add `.Length` to detect if the item has child elements.

Comment: @y3z1 Actually my question is : to query normally we use app.query(a => a.Id("someID")) . But how to query inside a list ? i.e.., in selenium we use like below : IList MyList;                                                       
 IWebElement element1 = MyList.FindElements(By........); I want to do something like this. Could you show me how exactly to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean getting the element inside a list view using an id? Try to add the **Id** function like `app.Query(q => q.Id("element_id").Child().Id(id_string));`.

Comment: @y3z1 Thanks . My List has A, B and C rows.                                                       And each Row A,B and C - has aa, bb and cc elements.                                          All the Rows has the same ID.                                                                               
AND "aa" element has the same ID in Row A,B and C. Similarly for bb and cc.    Now i want to go inside the first row A in the list and inside the row A, i want to read aa,bb and cc. How do i do this ? Kindly help me with this. Struggling a lot

Comment: The three rows correspond with these index of the list. Try to use **.Index()** function to get each row element and then get the children in this row. Such as `app.Query(q => q.Id("element_id").Child().Index(1).Id(id_string))`;

Comment: @y3z1 Thought it would work. Unfortunately it's not working :(

Comment: @y3z1 Could you please help me

Comment: Where did you want to get the child element? A ListView? A similar issue case link you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36500598/11083277